# write html when a href is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In an unordered list i have some a's with some href's. When clicked I want some html from an external file written. I cannot use any server side languages since it only gonna be running localy.

The structure of my file is:

```
<body>
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">item1</li>
    <li><a href="#">item2</li>
    <li><a href="#">item3</li>
    <li><a href="#">item4</li>
</ul>

<div id="content">
<!-- when a link is clicked write some html from external file to this spot-->
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: `document.write` will obliterate the current document. This means that your **whole page** will be replaced by whatever it is you're "writing".

Comment: is that the whole code? you are missing the jquery tag inside head, have you checked your browser's javascript console for any error?

Comment: also, are triangle, square and ball.js really big? if they are small why don't you put them on one main js file loaded on head and just call the required function on click?

Answer (score 1):

Since it looks like you're trying to load a script, there's a better way to do that, by using [`jQuery.getScript()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/):

```
$('#triangle').click(function() {
    $.getScript("js/triangle.js");
});
```

Also, as arieljuod points out, you haven't actually loaded jQuery in your HTML file. You'll need to do that to use it:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

(Or pick your favorite jQuery version and CDN; this is one of many.)

Answer (score 0):

You don't want `document.write()`.

You probably want this instead, depending on where you want the new HTML to go:

```
$('head').append('<script src="js/square.js"></script>');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can listen for a click on an item and based on that trigger an ajax call for the appropriate file. Load the contents of that file into your content div within the success callback.

Happy to walk you through sample code live over here: https://sudonow.com/session/525cb34035e089113700000a

Pasting the content of the code editor here:

```
<body>
<ul>
    <li id="item1" class="item"><a href="#">item1</li>
    <li id="item3" class="item"><a href="#">item2</li>
    <li id="item4" class="item"><a href="#">item3</li>
    <li id="item5" class="item"><a href="#">item4</li>
</ul>

<div id="content">
<!-- when a link is clicked write some html from external file to this spot-->
</div>
</body>

</html>

//JS
//convert some file content to html
var genHtmlContent = function(content){
  //do something here depending on how data is stored e.g. we could just return an html string from some keyvalue json
  return content.htmlContent;
}

//Use javascript to detect a click on a list item and grab the appropriate content
$("item").click(function(event){
  var selectedId = event.target.id;
  var url = "http://www.mysite.com/" + selectedId + ".json";
  $.get(url, function(content) {
    var htmlContent = genHtmlContent(content);
    $("#content").val(htmlContent);
  })

})

//sample json file on server

//item1.json

{htmlContent: "<div>I am Item 1</div>"}
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick and easy solution will be an `iframe`. Add as many iframes as you want, each having a different url. Give them a common class and hide them using CSS or jQuery. On clicking a link, prevent default and show the corresponding iframe, like;

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#" id="item1">item1</li>
</ul>

<div id="content">
<iframe class="iframes" id="iframe1" src="http://www.page1.com"></iframe> 
</div>
```

and in your JavaScript, add this;

```
$('.iframes').hide();
$('#item1').click(function() {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#iframe1').show();
});
```